# How to modify a XPM image using GNU Emacs?

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open and edit images in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640112/how-to-open-and-edit-images-in-emacs)

I know that Vim and XEmacs can modify XPM images.
How can I do it using GNU Emacs?
[image: Vim]
[image: XEmacs]

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640112/how-to-open-and-edit-images-in-emacs This is asking about an equivalent to GVim's xpm editing mode.

Comment: Note, regular Vim can't do this, GVim is required.

Answer (score 2):

Open your image like a regular file, and Emacs will display it. If you then C-c C-c (image-toggle-display) then you'll get the image code, and you can edit it, technically.