# How to open and edit images in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have searched a lot about opening image inside Emacs. I think [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) will do the trick, but what I don't seem to be able to find is a way to use this inside Emacs and how to integrate it with Emacs?!

Besides, any better alternative will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Image-Dired](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/emacs_notes_cheat_sheets.html#sec8).

It is already included in Emacs. Just type `M-x image-dired` and choose an appropriate  directory.

Comment: yep, I was very very happy too the first time I saw it :) a limitation though, is that we can't preview video thumbnails, and it seems like nobody's ever done it. We shall use emms for videos then http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EMMS, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something like the [Emacs Image Manipulation mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsImageManipulation)? It uses mogrify from ImageMacgick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am looking for a way that I don't need to switch mode for this purpose? if this is at all possible..

Comment: I'm new to Emacs: 1) Do I need to install ImageMagick for this first? 2) Where should I put this .el file? thx

Comment: @Luke you will need ImageMagick installed because the elisp code calls `mogrify`. Place the .el file in your `emacs.d` directory in your home directory and make sure `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")` is somewhere in your .emacs file. Then just add the hooks from the page to your .emacs file

Comment: I have done what you said but when I want to open a file it shows me the code of the image instead of the image! can you advice me how to proceed?

Comment: @Luke are you sure you're using some type of image mode? Otherwise you can `M-x image-mode`. You can switch between text and image by `C-c C-c`, and make sure you're not running emacs *inside* a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean. You can open an image "inside Emacs" just like any other file, just `C-x C-f` to find it, and `C-c C-c` to toggle the bitmap rendering.

Code-wise, it looks like this:

```
(defimage test-image
    ((:file "~/Pictures/greenbug.xpm")))

(insert-image test-image)
```

Or even simpler

```
(insert-image (create-image "~/Pictures/greenbug.xpm"))
```